# Can we solve the longest increasing subsequence prob by designing the binary search tree and traverse its longest right?

Tags: algorithm

I have solved two ques with the same approach and it is providing me right answer.
[image]

Comment: Is this a practical programming-related question?

Answer (score 0):

No.

'Subsequence' means the original order in the array should be preserved, but if you insert the items into a binary search tree, you lose the original order, since binary search trees insert items in BST order.